# how can I echo something without newline with osascript in `run script` workflow in alfred?

Tags: javascript, echo, console.log, osascript, alfred

I wrote some script in alfred workflow with osascript(js). As we known,  `console.log` will left an `undefined` after echo the log to stdout, we could not use it to pass the result to the workflow outputs like `clipboard`. And then I found I can use eval or just run a expression to pass something to the stdout. But we known that it would add an newline to the stdout. And then, I got a result tailing with a newline, which was additional. It was not a perfect way to resolve my problem. Is there any other resolutions?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Function of the code could be ignored. Just focus on how to echo without a newline tailing. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: @Jordan Added. But I think the code is less important in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find a way to use osascript(JS) to do that. But there's another way.

1. Change script language from osascript(JS) to bash.
2. Script: get result of your osascript, trim the extra newline.

   ```
   osascript -l JavaScript process.js "{query}" | tr -d '\n'
   ```
3. Parse your code to process.js in workflow folder. Add code to read arguments from command line. (special thanks to [mikaelbr/node-osascript](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-osascript/blob/master/examples/js/osascript.js))

   ```
   var app = Application.currentApplication();
   app.includeStandardAdditions = true;

   ObjC.import('Cocoa');
   var args = ObjC.deepUnwrap($.NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments).slice(4);

   var query = args[0].split(' ');
   var set1 = query[0].split(',');
   var set2 = query[1].split(',');
   var res = set1.filter(function (id,index){
       return set2.indexOf(id) != -1;
   })
   res.join(query[2] || ',')
   ```

Comment: That might be the best alternative solution I ever saw.

Answer (score 3):

Alfred 3.0 now has a "Trim Whitespace" [transform](https://www.alfredapp.com/help/workflows/utilities/transform/). You can find it under right-click > Utilities > Transform.

[image]